# migrating from yesod 0.8 to 0.9

Tags: yesod

I have just upgraded to yesod 0.9 and I am getting this error below, which is not mentioned in the upgrade guide in the Michael's announcement (http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/08/yesod-0-9-release-candidate):

`` config\Settings.hs:27:18:
    Could not find module `Text.Lucius': ``

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to add`shakespeare-css`to my`.cabal`file.